# Nuxt 3 error: s.replaceAll is not a function

Tags: npm, nuxt.js

When I run Nuxt 3 from npm I get the error "s.replaceAll is not a function." This also happens when the "nuxt prepare" post-install script runs. Here's my package.json file

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@iconify/vue": "^4.1.1",
    "@nuxtjs/google-fonts": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "nuxt": "^3.4.2",
    "@nuxt/kit": "^3.4.2",
    "sass": "^1.61.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.4.1",
    "vuetify": "^3.2.2",
    "@mdi/font": "^7.2.96",
    "vite-plugin-vuetify": "^1.0.2"
  }
}
```

Here's the error:

```
 ERROR  s.replaceAll is not a function                                                                                                                    10:34:33 AM  

  at /C:/path/to/project/node_modules/unhead/dist/index.mjs:278:13
  at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at processTemplateParams (/C:/path/to/project/node_modules/unhead/dist/index.mjs:275:10)
  at tags:resolve (/C:/path/to/project/node_modules/unhead/dist/index.mjs:301:31)
  at /C:/path/to/project/node_modules/hookable/dist/index.mjs:48:66
  at Object.run (/C:/path/to/project/node_modules/hookable/dist/index.mjs:41:43)
  at /C:/path/to/project/node_modules/hookable/dist/index.mjs:48:56
  at async Object.resolveTags (/C:/path/to/project/node_modules/unhead/dist/index.mjs:995:7)
  at async renderSSRHead (/C:/path/to/project/node_modules/@unhead/ssr/dist/index.mjs:77:23)
  at async initNitro (/C:/path/to/project/node_modules/nuxt/dist/index.mjs:2179:21)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah turns out I was using Node v14 instead of v16, which is required for Nuxt to work. It also turns out my PATH environment variable also had an entry to a v14 node installation, which is why having NVM switch to v16 didn't work.